W3 total cache two versions of the same page based on a string query in the url
I'm using W3 total cache. I would like to cache two different versions of the same page based on a string url query. For example I want my-domain.com to have a cached paged version "A" and my-domain.com/?new-version to use cached page version B.
Any help or thoughts are welcome!
When Cache SSL (HTTPS) Requests is enabled then caching works but then it uses only one cached page version.
I have Cache URIs With Query String Variables enabled.
I've added my query string ("new-version") to the Accepted Query Strings
I have in the page cache settings disk: basic
